# Removing certain tags with beautifulsoup and python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, strip

**Question**

I am trying to remove style tags like `<h2>` and `<div class=...>` from my html file which is being downloaded by BeautifulSoup. I do want to keep what the tags contain (like text)
However this does not seem to work.

**What i have tried**

```
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find("div", {"class": "product_specifications bottom_l js_readmore_content"})
    print "<hr style='border-width:5px;'>"
    for style in table.find_all('style'):
        if 'style' in style.attrs:
            del style.attrs['style']
    print table
```

**Urls i tried to work with**

[Python HTML parsing with beautiful soup and filtering stop words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629773/python-html-parsing-with-beautiful-soup-and-filtering-stop-words)

[Remove class attribute from HTML using Python and lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037289/remove-class-attribute-from-html-using-python-and-lxml)

[BeautifulSoup Tag Removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934562/beautifulsoup-tag-removal)

Comment: You haven't explained what doesn't work with your current solution.

Comment: it is stil styled as of its original page.

Comment: You want to use `tag.unwrap()`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `decompose()`:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose

If you want to clear just text or keep element removed from tree, use `clear` and `extract` (description just above decompose).

Comment: i stil need to keep its contents. The only thing i want to remove are the tags itself. because it styles my document which i do not want

Comment: So please explain it in question, not I comments

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for unwrap().

your_soup.tag.unwrap()